# Record incoming Twilio call

Tags: twilio

I am trying to record an INCOMING Twilio call. According to this documentation https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010317333-Recording-Incoming-Twilio-Voice-Calls it is possible to do so but the document is a bit confusing. I tried

> ```
> await this.client?.calls(callSid).recordings.create({
>       recordingStatusCallback: <my_url>
>       recordingStatusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
>       recordingStatusCallbackEvent: ['completed', 'failed'],
>     });
> ```

I keep getting: `Requested resource is not eligible for recording`
I am express.js and deploying to AWS Lambda. Does anyone know how to properly record an inbound call?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The message "Requested resource is not eligible for recording" typically means you are [trying to record a call that has already been completed](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/troubleshooting#recording-resource-exceptions).

[The documentation](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010317333-Recording-Incoming-Twilio-Voice-Calls) you were following does say:

> **Notice:** You won’t be able to begin recording the call until Twilio receives and processes your TwiML response. Since your application will receive the Call SID prior to this, it’s possible that an API request to begin recording your call can be submitted too early, resulting in an error. To minimize this possibility, we recommend instituting a delay before submitting your API request, and/or retrying your record requests if they fail.

You can solve this in JavaScript by delaying your call to the REST API and ensuring you have responded to the TwiML webhook first. Something like this might work:

```js
app.post("/incoming", (req, res) => {
  const callSid = req.body.CallSid;
  const twiml = Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  twiml.dial(NUMBER_TO_DIAL);
  res.set("Content-Type", "text/xml");

  // Send response
  res.send(twiml.toString());

  // Set timer to wait 1 second and then start recording
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.client.calls(callSid).recordings.create({
      recordingStatusCallback: <my_url>
      recordingStatusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
      recordingStatusCallbackEvent: ['completed', 'failed'],
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You are amazing man, thank you